# How to create a VPC endpoint for autoscaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-vpc

We have our VPCs not directly connected to internet. So we need CLI --endpoint-url option to send commands to the custom VPC endpoints instead of standard AWS service endpoints
e.g.

```
aws sns publish --message $MESSAGE  --target-arn $SNSTARGET --region $REGION --endpoint-url 'https://vpce-xxxx-xxxxx.sns.ap-southeast-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/'
```

For autoscaling though:
I can't find any vpc endpoint interface option and the EC2 endpoint is not accepted.

```
aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action --lifecycle-hook-name $LIFECYCLEHOOKNAME --auto-scaling-group-name $ASGNAME --lifecycle-action-result $HOOKRESULT --instance-id $INSTANCEID  --region $REGION
```

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL: https://autoscaling.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/

If I try to use the closest endpoint i.e. EC2

```
aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action --lifecycle-hook-name $LIFECYCLEHOOKNAME --auto-scaling-group-name $ASGNAME --lifecycle-action-result $HOOKRESULT --instance-id $INSTANCEID  --region $REGION --endpoint-url 'https://vpce-xxxx-xxx.ec2.ap-southeast-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/'
```

> An error occurred (InvalidAction) when calling the CompleteLifecycleAction operation: The action CompleteLifecycleAction is not valid for this web service.

Comment: Yes, it appears that the list of [Interface VPC Endpointshttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html) does not include `autoscaling`.

Comment: There should be some way to make this work or has it failed us?

Comment: An alternative might be for you to create your own [Amazon API Gateway Private Endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/) that receives the request and sends it to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

AWS will be adding EC2 autoscaling VPC endpoint in the coming weeks, the rumor is before Re:Invent.

Comment: This is now live:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-ec2-auto-scaling-application-auto-scaling-aws-auto-scaling-support-aws-privatelink/